# SQL Query to find the most recent group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a history of records (multiple records per update all with the exact same datetime) that share an `IdString`.

I want a query to determine which of these records are part of the most recent update group.

This query will show me *one* of the records having the most recent update date, but **for each partition, I need all the records with that max date**.

```
;with cte as(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by IdString order by UpdateDate desc) as [rn], *
from MyTable
)
select  CASE WHEN (cte.rn = 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [IsOld], *
from MyTable m
inner join cte on cte.RecordId= m.RecordId
```

Would someone please help me figure out an appropriate query?

**EDIT: Sample**

```
(IsOld is the desired calculated value)

IsOld RecordId  IdString  UpdateDate
1         1     ABC 2011-06-16 
1         2     ABC 2012-05-30 
1         3     ABC 2008-12-31 
0         4     ABC 2012-06-08 
1         5     ABC 2011-01-16 
0         6     ABC 2012-06-08 
1         7     ABC 2012-06-07 
1         8     XYZ 2001-01-16
1         9     XYZ 2013-01-30
0         10    XYZ 2001-01-31
1         11    XYZ 2013-06-01
1         12    XYZ 2001-05-04
0         13    XYZ 2013-01-30
```

Comment: Can you provide some test data and desired result?

Comment: Check my updated answer based on the new sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY IdString ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) AS [row_num], *
    FROM   MyTable
)
SELECT CASE WHEN m.[row_num] = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END isOld, *
from cte m
```

Comment: Rank() is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN updateDate = maxDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END isOldRecord, RecordID, IDString, UpdateDate
FROM 
(
select  m.RecordID, m.IDString, m.updateDate, MAX(UpdateDate) OVER (PARTITION BY IDString) maxDate
    from MyTable m
) A
```

Comment: This solution does the job nicely. Thank you very much for your help, and for answering first, but I prefer the RANK() query.